# fiware spagobi api rest validate with keyrock

Tags: rest, fiware, spagobi

I have 3 instances:

1.- app web (ubuntu instance)

2.- keyrock instance

3.- spagobi instance

My spagobi instance works validating users with keyrock as the same as App web. I create some reports in it. Now, i need to get these reports to insert into my app web.

Im trying to use http://docs.spagobi.apiary.io/, **The preview subresource** option. But all times i have a modal window asking my user/pass (as a apache security option).

im using **http://spagobi-url/SpagoBI/restful-services/2.0/documents/printers_visited/preview** (printers visited is the label of my document). And results:

[image: apache authentication]

If i wrote my user/pass in this panel, validation dont work and tries as a loop.

Anyone know how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

the REST services provided by SpagoBI require basic authentication, that's why you see the modal window asking for credentials.
In order to avoid this, you should implement a SSO between your application and SpagoBI and open a session in SpagoBI: when the session is opened, you should be able to invoke REST services.
Pay attention to the fact that preview subresource is just a static (optional file), it is not the executed report: if you want to execute the report, you should get the content subresource.
Just to let you know, we are currently developing possibility to invoke REST services providing the OAuth token. This should be available in next release.

Hope this helps

Comment: oh! that's bad news for me :( my app uses Keyrock in all cases (spagobi, poi, and other services). is it possible to configure spagobi to use keyrock and sso at the same time (for example, configuring an admin-user in spagobi)?

Comment: It is possible to use Keyrock and SSO at the same time, but it is quite complicated and it requires developments. For details, have a look at SpagoBI Wiki [SSO](http://wiki.spagobi.org/xwiki/bin/view/spagobi_server/sso) and [users' management](http://wiki.spagobi.org/xwiki/bin/view/spagobi_server/User+Management_v3) pages.